# Renewal SSL certificate - DigitalOcean with Ubuntu and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04

Aside from the tutorials from DigitaOcean I was able to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64, Apache, hire an SSL certificate on GoDaddy, and make it all work perfectly on my Droplet. However, a year has passed and my SSL certificate has expired and I do not know where to get my certificate back to work (remembering that I have renewed the certificate with GoDaddy for another year).

What would be the workflow for renewing my SSL certificate on my Droplet on DigitalOcean running Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64 and Apache. Do I have to redo the whole process or is there an 'easy' way? Sorry for the question, but I'm new to this subject.

Comment: Did you ask GoDaddy? You brought something from them and have a problem with it so they would surely be able to help you out…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, unless you have a specific reason for not doing so, I would ignore you ever got a certificate, and go through exactly the same process as you did the first time.

You already know how to do it, you know it works, and so long as you only every used the private key linked to the cert for your webserver, then I don't see any harm in just creating a new key.

That being said, you might not need to do any of that, if you can use [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) instead of GoDaddy.

They are free, and more importantly for your needs, automate the request and renewal process, via [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

If you don't like certbot, there are [alternatives](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/).